# Did I answer this probability question correctly?

Tags: probability

Hello I have the following question to answer:

`Imagine three boxes, each of which has three slips of paper in it each with a number
marked on it. The numbers for box A are 2, 4 and 9, for box B 1, 6 and 8, and for box C
3, 5 and 7. One slip is drawn, independently and with equal probability, from each box.`

`Compute P{A Slip > B slip}` (a slip taken from A is greater than a slip from B)

My attempted solution:

First note the possible outcomes: (highlighted are outcomes that satisfy A>B)

`{2,1}` || {2,6} || {2,8}

`{4,1}` || {4,6} || {4,8}

`{9,1}` || `{9,6}` || `{9,8}`

Since there are 5 possible outcomes where A>B and since the events are independent from one another then the probability is simply:

(5/9) * P{B|A}, where B is a slip chosen from B that is smaller than A

The probability P{B|A} is P{B|2} + P{B|4} + P{B|9} = 0+1/3+1 = 4/3

So finally P{Aslip>Bslip} = (5/9)(4/3) = 20/27 or 74%

Comment: Needs work. Can't have $\Pr(B|A)=4/3$. The required probability will be $5/9$.

Comment: @AndreNicolas thought this was strange when I put that. So should P{B|A} simply be P{B}? since they are independent so that gives us 1/3?

Comment: i think possible outcomes $2,1 - 4,1 - 9,1 - 9,6 - 9,8$ prob $=5/9$     its independent of $C$

Comment: Three cases: (i) A got $2$, B got $1$; (ii) A got $4$, B got $1$; (iii) A got $9$, B got anything.  So $(1/3)(1/3)+(1/3)(1/3)+(1/3)(3/3)$.

Comment: @andreNicolas ahh so I did unnecessary work at the end and could have stopped at 5/9? You should make it an answer! thank you

Comment: @mert thank you, I guess I was over thinking this one and made it more difficult than I had to, my answer was simply 5/9 haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $3$ equally likely possibilities for A's number, $2$, $4$, and $9$.

If A got $2$, then the probability that A beat B is $\frac{1}{3}$, for B must get $1$.

If A got $4$, then again the probability that A beat B is $\frac{1}{3}$.

If A got $9$, then the probability that A beat B is $1$, or more prettily $\frac{3}{3}$.

Thus the probability that A beats B is $\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{3}$.

**Remark:** Your counting argument gave the same result, but then got spoiled.

The problem will become interesting when you compute the probability that B beats C, and the probability that C beats A.

Comment: Actually that is the next part of the question! P{B>C} then P{C>A} haha Now I'm worried about these

Comment: Very similar procedures. The interesting part will be when you compare the results (non-transitivity of "beats").

Comment: I just computed the cases where B beats C and C beats A using this method and I got 5/9 for both...why Do I feel like this is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First, calculate the total possible ways you can draw 3 slips. There are 3 choices for $A$, 3 for $B$, and 3 for box $C$ giving a total of $3(3)(3)=27$ total possible ways to draw slips.

Notice what you draw from the 3rd box doesn't matter at all. So we can calculate the ways to draw slips such that # slip $A>$ # slip $B$ and just know that for each way we could do that there are 3 choices for $C$.

Because the events are independent, if we draw $1$ from $B$ there are 3 choices that I can draw from $A$ that satisfy what we want and of course 3 choices for $C$. If we draw $6$ there is only one choice, $9$, that we can draw from $A$ to get what we want (and $3$ choices for $C$). Similarly, if we draw $8$ from $B$. Then there are $3(3)+3(1)+3(1)=15$ total ways to get the desired outcome. That gives a probability of $\frac{15}{27}=\frac{5}{9}=55.\overline{5}\%$ probability of the desired event occurring.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I would up-vote if I could!!